# Modify List Forms with SP Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, list-form

I want to change the width of the fields and make the picture links viewed as an image not as an URL in the Display Form.

I can modify list views with SP Designer but I don't know how to modify the list forms.

In List views there are FieldRefs and I use them. But for Forms I don't know how to do it.

I tried InfoPath but it gives me error so I want to try to do it with SP Designer. How can I modify the forms?

DispForm.aspx:

```
<WebPartPages:ListFormWebPart runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{CD67A8BB-D671-4E51-ADF9-0B5E3C22FBB2}" >
<WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>MyList</Title>
  <FrameType>Default</FrameType>
  <Description />
  <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
  <ZoneID>Main</ZoneID>
  <PartOrder>1</PartOrder>
  <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
  <Height />
  <Width />
  <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
  <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
  <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
  <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
  <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
  <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
  <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
  <DetailLink />
  <HelpLink />
  <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
  <Dir>Default</Dir>
  <PartImageSmall />
  <MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>
  <PartImageLarge />
  <IsIncludedFilter />
  <ExportControlledProperties>true</ExportControlledProperties>
  <ConnectionID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ConnectionID>
  <ID>g_cd67a8bb_d671_4e51_adf9_0b5e3c22fbb2</ID>
  <ListName xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">{C56882D8-7380-43CB-A682-D2D18EA0700E}</ListName>
  <ListId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">c56882d8-7380-43cb-a682-d2d18ea0700e</ListId>
  <PageType xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">PAGE_DISPLAYFORM</PageType>
  <FormType xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">4</FormType>
  <ControlMode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">Display</ControlMode>
  <ViewFlag xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">1</ViewFlag>
  <ViewFlags xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">Html</ViewFlags>
  <ListItemId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">0</ListItemId>
</WebPart>
</WebPartPages:ListFormWebPart>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found how to do it.

1. In SP Designer create a new Display Form
2. Preview the form or F12
3. Edit Page
4. Edit Web Part
5. In Data View Properties click XSL Editor

Here I edited the view like I edited the list view.

Comment: If you solved the problem statet in your original question, you should mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.technock.net/2012/07/sharepoint-designer-2010-create-custom.html

http://blog.technock.net/2012/07/sharepoint-designer-2010-create-custom.html

Custom List forms creation or Modification similar Features in  SP Designer 2010 & 2013.

Comment: I'm using SP 2013. So there is no design view in SP Designer 2013 and I don't want to add/remove field. I want to modify them.

Comment: SP Designer 2010 is incompatible with an SP 2013 site.